# monotouch startup window

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

just wondering how to set startup window of monotouch application...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the same way you do in the standard environment. Create a image, put it in resources with the name "default.png". <strike>The application objects loads and displays it automatically.</strike>(Edit: Actually, I think the system displays the image while the app loads.)